# transpose one row with multi-fields columns to multi rows

Tags: excel

Let’s say we have a `xlsx` file, which contains hundreds of rows in below format:

```
name time1 theater1 time2 theater2 time3 theater3
Nomadland 09/02/2022 Theater A 09/04/2022 Theater A 09/07/2022 Theater B
```

I want to transpose this table from one movie with multiple screening time and screening theater in one row, into multiple rows with one screening time and screening theater in one row, which the final result will look like:

```
name time theater
Nomadland 09/02/2022 Theater A 
Nomadland 09/04/2022 Theater A
Nomadland 09/07/2022 Theater B
```

Currently, I’m using `openpyxl` in Python to finish this process. But I’m wondering is there a solution in vanilla `Excel` way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

*Assumes all movies will be in a single row*
*You should be able to add unlimited theater/time column pairs, and movies*

Basic algorithm:

- Unpivot all columns except for the `name`
- group by the `name` and the numeric part of the theater and or time col labels (which are in a column after the unpivot)
- extract the time and theater from each grouping

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//routine in case you have unlimited "pairs" of columns in Source data
    colHeaders = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    transforms = List.Transform(List.Alternate(colHeaders,1,1,0), each {_, type date}) &  
                  List.Transform(List.Alternate(colHeaders,1,1,1), each {_, type text}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, transforms),

//Unpivot except for the Name column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//split column to get theater/time number
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Attribute.1","Attribute.2"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{"Attribute.1"}),

//groub by name & theater/time number and extract the theater and time
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"name","Attribute.2"}, {
        {"time", each [Value]{0}, type date},
        {"theater" ,each [Value]{1}, type text}
        }),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Attribute.2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]